# Normalizer of normalizer of maximal torus in a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

I'm stuck at this problem,

> Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and $T$ a maximal torus. Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. Let $N(T)$ and $N(H)$ denote the normalizers of $T$ and $H$ respectively. Show that if $N(T) \subset H $then $N(H) = H$.

I was able to show that $N(H)/H$ should be finite. But showing this only used the fact that $T \subset H$. Because this question can no longer be reduced to a question about Lie algebras, I am not able to see how to proceed.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? Suppose $n \in G$ normalizes $H$. Then $nTn^{-1}$ is a maximal torus of $H$. All maximal tori of $H$ are conjugate, so this means the new torus is $h^{-1}Th$ for some $h \in H$. Multiplying through to remove inverses, we see $hn \in G$ normalizes $T$. By assumption, then, $hn$ is in $H$, so $n$ must be too.

Comment: "All maximal tori of $H$ are conjugate, so this means the new torus is $h^{-1}Th$ for some $h \in H$." How? Note that $T$ isn't a maximal torus in $H$.

Comment: If we use $N(T)\subset H $, then that follows.